# Unknown attribute access in <sec:authorize> tag

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, primefaces

I have just implemented **spring security** in my **primefaces** project.
The authentication between pages is working so well, but I am can't check the roles of users.

Here is my hello.html file

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">

<h:head>
  <title>PrimeFaces Hello World Example</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

  <div class="authorization-div">
    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
      <p:outputLabel value="You have the USER role" />
    </sec:authorize>
    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
      <p:outputLabel value="You have the ADMIN role" />
    </sec:authorize>
    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOM')">
      <p:outputLabel value="You have the CUSTOM role" />
    </sec:authorize>
  </div>
```

The output HTML of my localhost:8080/hello.xhtml is:

## You have the USER role You have the ADMIN role You have the CUSTOM role

## ...

I am using MyEclipse Editor and it keeps giving me a warning says "unknown attribute 'access'" in lines start with

**<sec:authorize access="**

I want to retrieve the roles of the authenticated users and please reply anyone knowing the problem above or has encounter with this before.

Comment: Are you sure you've configured properly the users? The code looks correct, so please post all your configurations, to replicate your example.

Comment: I works fine now! This is really strange. After I had lunch and log in again and it works. I think user role management is not updating realtime. And MyEclipse is still giving me a warning "can't find tag". Is this okay? Because I really hate seeing warning.